# How to access elements in a specific way in json?

Tags: python, json

I want to learn JSON and I am using Python. I currently have a question about how to access elements. Here would be a generic example of the JSON information:

```
"data":{
   "Bob":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"30",
      "state":"California",
      "job":"accountant"
   },
   "Joe":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"30",
      "state":"Florida",
      "job":"engineer"
   },
   "Tom":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"25",
      "state":"North Dakota",
      "job":"manager"
   }
}
```

Now, I would want to make a `for` loop that gets a list of all the names that are age 30. How am I going to do this. I tried doing something like this:

```
array = []
for x in range(0,3):
    if data[x]['age'] is '30' 
    array.append(data[x])
```

but that is definitely wrong. Can somebody teach me how to sort the items in JSON in this way?

Comment: What did you expect to get as a result? Why do you think that your code is wrong?

Comment: You're iterating through a dict.  How to do this is covered in any tutorial on dicts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {
  "Bob":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"30",
      "state":"California",
      "job":"accountant"
   },
   "Joe":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"30",
      "state":"Florida",
      "job":"engineer"
   },
   "Tom":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"25",
      "state":"North Dakota",
      "job":"manager"
   }
}

names = []
for name, information in data.items():
    if information['age'] == '30':
        names.append(name)

print(names)
```

If you have a dictionary object called data, you can use data.items() to iterate over the keys ('Bob', 'Joe', 'Tom') and values of the dictionary. You could check out the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: As OP mentioned he's new; you should try providing more of an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate via JSON data the same as via Python dict

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    input_data = json.load(json_file)

data = []
# use dict function items that iterate via key, value in our cause k - key, v - value
for k, v in input_data['data'].items():
    if v['age'] == '30':
        data.append(v)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30', 'state': 'California', 'job': 'accountant'}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': '30', 'state': 'Florida', 'job': 'engineer'}]
```

Comment: That’s because in your example it *is* a Python dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

```
json_data = {"data":{
   "Bob":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"30",
      "state":"California",
      "job":"accountant"
   },
   "Joe":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"30",
      "state":"Florida",
      "job":"engineer"
   },
   "Tom":{
      "name":"Bob",
      "age":"25",
      "state":"North Dakota",
      "job":"manager"
   }
}
}
names = []
for k, v in json_data['data'].items():
  if v['age'] == '30':
    names.append(k)

print(names)
```